# DB2/400 SQL : How to insert PDF file in Blob Column?

Tags: db2-400

I would like to know if my SQL insert code is OK.

Here is my table :

```
-- Create table
Create table FNS_CHAMP_DEV
( 
IDAUTO         Integer not null generated always as identity ( start with 
0, increment by 1, no cache) primary key,
BB_COL               BLOB,  
CB_COL               CLOB   
);
```

Is my syntax SQL below correct to insert  a PDF file in BLOB Column ?

-- SQL insert request :

```
   SELECT IDAUTO  AS Last_ID from final table  (Insert into FNS_CHAMP_DEV  ( 
   BB_COL ) Values(blob('C:\DOC_TECHNIQUE_WD\TEC_VISUAL_STUDIO\WPF_VISUAL_STUDIO.pdf')));
```

Thanks

Comment: OK so this question and the other one you posted are linked.  Let's start here.  The solution you show here will not insert the PDF.  It will insert the string containing the path to the PDF.  In the other question, you asked about opening the image or PDF on Windows.  What language are you using to handle the file I/O? I doubt you are using SQL for that purpose.  Where are you running SQL from?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I undrestand that my solution ( of my first question) is not OK. So, for my first question ( how to insert .PDF file or .JPG picture in a blob column), what is the right method ?

Comment: I did not find an example on the IBM (for SQL DB2 / 400) web page illustrating a method for inserting data into a BLOB type column....

Comment: Yes the examples on IBM's page are not great.  I'm not sure you even can insert a binary file into DB2 using only SQL.  Everything I know about using BLOB columns requires using a seperate host language.  We have programs that do this through VB and RPGLE.  That's why I keep asking what other language you are using.  In order to insert the actual image data, you need to be able to read the raw data from the image and insert that into the BLOB column from a data array.  Reading from a BLOB column is the opposite process.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.  Do you think it's possible to have an exemple with VB ?

Comment: Microsoft has an example on inserting an image into a BLOB field here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316887/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-to-and-from-a-blob-column-by-using-ado-ne.  If that doesn't work for you, I'll try and come up with a minimum useful example.